# Issue with 2 version of python (2.6.6 and 2.7) with pip

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, module, pip

I have default python version 2.6.6 and pip is working with that. But
when I installed `python2.7`, it was installed in different path(
`/usr/local/bin/python2.7`). My main concern is pip is not working with
2.7 and getting error `No module named pip`. Is it possible to install separate pip for 2.7 or we can use existing pip with 2.7. Please
suggest.

```
[jack@server ~]$ python --version
Python 2.6.6
[jack@server ~]$ which python
/usr/bin/python
[jack@server ~]$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
[jack@server ~]$ which python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
[jack@server ~]$ python2.7 --version
Python 2.7
[jack@server ~]$ sudo python2.7 -m pip install pymongo
[sudo] password for jack:
/usr/local/bin/python2.7: No module named pip
```

Comment: you will need to install pip seperately. How did you install python 2.7?

Comment: I installed from   wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/Python-2.7.tgz
# tar zxvf Python-2.7.tgz
# cd Python-2.7
# ./configure
# sudo make altinstall (to keep parallel version)

Comment: Then you should be safe to just follow the [get pip install  guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Comment: Are you suggesting below steps:- 1. curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py 2.python2.7 get-pip.py  Will it be installed in /usr/local/bin/?

Comment: Yes, since you compiled from source and did not use a package manager to install python, you should be able to install pip this way.

Comment: Will it going to impact my existing pip or environment ? Is there any version or way from which we can install both python and pip. I guess after 2.7.9, it automatically installs pip

Comment: What is your usecase? Why do do you even need python 2.7 (which has reached end of life). You could just locally install miniconda and then create a python 2.7 environment